# get same 12 variables from 8 classes in different packages java

Tags: java

I am wondering if there is a way to get multiple variables (12 of them) from 8 different classes in different packages:
(Humans.Old (3 of 8), Humans.Adult (2 of 8), and Humans.Child (3 of 8)).
Here is an example of one of the classes:

```
package Humans.Adult;

import Humans.BaseHuman;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Brother extends BaseHuman {
    public void init() {
        List<Integer> startingItemCodes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        startingItemCodes.add(0);

        setMAX_SANE(110); // Part of getters and setters in BaseHuman.java
        setMAX_WATER(110); // This also
        setMAX_HUNGER(110); // This also
        setHEALTH(100); // This also

        setHUNGER_DEC(10); // This also
        setSANE_DEC(10); // This also
        setWATER_DEC(10); // This also

        setHEALTH_DEC_HUNGER(10); // This also
        setHEALTH_DEC_THIRST(10); // This also

        setSICK_CHANCE(0.05f); // This also
        setNAME("Brother"); // This also
        setSTARTING_ITEMS(startingItemCodes); // This also
    }
}
```

So, for each of the 8 classes like the top one, can I call all of the 12 getter methods extended by BaseHuman, so I would end up calling 96 getter methods. Sorry, I'm fairly new to Java.

How would I do this?

--Thanks!

Comment: Does this make sense? I tried to explain it the best I could...

Comment: no it doesnt make sense. i think u should first go ahead and give u some knowledge on oop principles. and for this problem specialy u need to know about inheritence principle well. also what is class, object. so just go through oop paradigm. as if u dont have this knowledge it quite impossible to give u a solution in a single answer.

Comment: No, it does not make sense.  Not to me, anyway.  I see no getter methods, but I don't understand why you're concerned that there might be an issue with invoking public methods on an object that that object's class in fact has.

Comment: Why do you need the getters? Are you trying to create an instance of the inherited object?

Comment: Also, separately, *please* use consensus Java naming conventions.  In particular, method names should be in camelCase, with the initial letter lowercase.  Example: `setMaxSane()`.  That makes it much easier on everyone reading your code -- maybe even you.

Comment: Sorry, I was using the name convention for enums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the advantages of inheritance is, that you can call the methods of BaseHuman on every Class that is inheriting from it (e.g. Brother). So you can make a list of BaseHuman like this:

```
ArrayList<BaseHuman> bhList = new ArrayList<BaseHuman>();
```

and then add Brothers and every thing else to the list.

```
Brother broA = new Brother();
Sister sisA = new Sister();
bhList.add(broA);
bhList.add(sisA);
```

then you could call getters from every Object that is stored in the list like this:

```
for(BaseHuman bh : bhList){
    System.out.println(bh.get());
}
```

The requirement is, that you overwrite the getter Method from the Superclass BaseHuman.

If you want to know more you can look into "Polymorphism".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the purpose behind the question, so if I misunderstood please let me know.

If you *really* just want to call all of the getters in every class, you can use @M.Dan's solution as he provided. But, to me it sounds like you are trying to create an instance of a class that inherits from `BaseHuman`, so you can change its properties. For example, maybe `OldHuman` has a lower value for `HEALTH` but is otherwise the same.

Instead of calling all the getters again to set the fields, you can simply use the `BaseHuman` class constructor by calling `super()`:

```
class OldHuman extends BaseHuman {

    public OldHuman() {
        super(); //invokes parent constructor which you supplied default values
        this.HEALTH = 75; //change HEALTH to desired amount instead
    }
}
```

This way, you save yourself rewriting all the fields 96 times, and only change what you need. And, your `OldHuman` will otherwise behave exactly the same (getters, setters, etc.)

If you still REALLY need to call all of the getters, you could at the very least write a method in `BaseHuman` that returns all fields in a Collection of some sort, and let your classes inherit that instead.